# Single word for "Getting a rough idea"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there one? Context: Trying to define a learning workflow like below in trello

Knowledge deficit area => Getting a rough idea => Building a foundation => Applying the knowledge

Comment: Current jargon in US education is "assessment."  Consider "initial assessment" in this context.

Comment: _introduction, introductory phase_

Comment: Conjecture, theorize, hypothesize, surmise, speculate sound okay?

Comment: First pass (or just pass) is something I see a lot of.  "Take a pass at it and see if it's doable".  Pass?  Outside of context it doesn't mean rough idea.  Still, I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I'd say ***gist*** if a noun, but I suppose I'd say *acquainting* if a progressive verb.

Comment: Acquainting sounds like an option -- short and memorable

Answer (score 2):

**draft** seems like it would fit.

It's both a verb and a noun.

> **[draft](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/draft)** - Any of various stages in the development of a plan, document, or picture:
>
> *First we'll identify the area of knowledge deficit, then we'll **draft** a solution.*
>
> *Here is a **draft** of our solution proposal.*

Answer (score 1):

reconnaissance

> preliminary surveying or research. "conducting client reconnaissance"